# Make html page take at least 100% of view port if content is too small

Tags: html, css

*Not-so-experienced developer here*

I am currently working on a web page with a "Header - Content - Footer" design.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <div class="header">
                HEADER
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                CONTENT
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- Header is a sticky div. Something like a navbar.
- Content can be of **ANY** size.
- Header and footer have fixed height.

I want the content div to take the remaining page space even when the content inside is not big enough to fill the div.

Here is the css that I came up with:

```css
html, body, #root {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
    margin: 0
}

.content {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.header, .footer {
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 56px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Although this works as intended** when the content is larger than the viewport, it doesn't on the opposite case.
When looking through a developer console, the height values of the *html, body, #root* tags rightfully equals 100% of the viewport, but the *content* div does not take the remaining space (even when specifying *height: 100%*).

**Why is that so?**

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c91p0yot/

Comment: What do you mean by remaining space, if it overflows the viewport height is it showing scrollbar?

Comment: Have you tried this  `.content {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
     overflow:auto;
}`

Comment: If it does not overflow, fit the content div to the remaining *room* available on the page, if it does, it shows a scrollbar

Comment: Adding `overflow: auto` changes nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the flexbox layout mode and make your `<body>` `display: flex;`

Then, give the `.content` a `flex` value of `1` which will force the `.content` to take up all remaining space.

Also get rid of the `#root` `div`

```css
html
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.content {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1;
}

.header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.header, .footer {
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 56px;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
}
```

Comment: It *does* the trick, but do you think it would be possible to do the same without `flex`? I'll mark as answer if not.

Comment: By the way does changing `100vh` to `100%` has any effect?

Comment: You can also use display: grid. The flex box solution is perfect for your scenario. There are also some tricks to make it work but flex box is designed for this type of thing.

Comment: @HeyShafty yes. 100% ensures that it will be bigger than the viewport if necessary.

Comment: I would use this approach for modern browsers & dev

Answer (score 1):

Set the content to be at least the height of the viewport minus the header and footer height.

```css
html, body, #root {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
    margin: 0
}

.content {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 112px);
}

.header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.header, .footer {
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 56px;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div class="header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      FOOTER
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```